# Maximum 1000 products per Customer Group Catalog Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, customer-group

I am currently workong on a 1.9 Community E Magento site that, unfortunately, has nearly 50,000 products. Aside from the Magento issues with that many products, I am utilizing the Amasty Customer Group Catalog plugin to asign a credit system to all products using a Customer Group Rule, but the Customer Group Rule caps out at 1000 products per rule, or it throws a token error.

**Are there any other options for this ruling other than creating 50 duplicates of the same rule and assigning roughly 1000 products to each?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the error you're getting is not related to the module but to your server configuration.

The point is, you're saying that **it starts failing from 1000 and I'm pretty sure that's caused by the default value of `max_input_vars` from PHP.**

Try changing this value from 1000 to something higher like 2000 and see how it goes.

If that fixes the issue until 2000 then try increasing it to the number of your groups I can't guarantee it will work but it could.

Keep in mind that this maximum is set to avoid hackers to exhaust your memory so you should definitely roll it back to its original value once you're done.

Comment: I've ran some test at ~5000 max_input_vars and that does seem to work. Is there a true "maximum" for max_input_vars, or am I relatively safe setting at ~50,000 for this one section and then returning it to 1000?

Comment: @nocc_ninja I reckon you should give it a try. To me you should try to do it for your script and keep in mind that this maximum is set to avoid hackers to exhaust your memory so you should definitely roll it back to its original value once you're done.